# GTMOAuth2Authentication Not Working

Tags: youtube, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, gtm-oauth2

I'm trying to use Google's OAuth2 and YouTube APIs. The OAuth returns `GTMOAuth2Authentication` object that you then use to make requests to services like YouTube. My login works fine, and when I manually pass the authentication object, I can make requests.

However, I should also be able to access the authentication object via keychain, and I receive a valid object, but if I try to use it to make requests, I cannot. I keep getting the following error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher error -1.)" I'd appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake. I'm testing on a real iPhone 5s.

Authentication Code:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                                                 initWithScope:scope
                                                 clientID:kGoogleClientID
                                                 clientSecret:kGoogleClientSecret
                                                 keychainItemName:kGoogleKeychainItemName
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:
                                                                            finishedWithAuth:
                                                                            error:)];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Authentication Completion Handler:

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }

    MediaGETWrapper *getWrapper = [MediaGETWrapper sharedWrapper];
    getWrapper.googleAuth = auth; // passing auth directly without keychain

    [getWrapper youTubeSubscriptionsWithSuccess:nil failure:nil];
```

YouTube Client Initialization:

```
self.youTube = [GTLServiceYouTube new];
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication new];

[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch
 authorizeFromKeychainForName:kGoogleKeychainItemName
 authentication:auth
 error:nil];

self.youTube.authorizer = auth;
```

Request:

```
- (void)youTubeSubscriptionsWithSuccess:(void(^)(NSArray *subscriptions))success
                                failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))error {

    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

//    self.youTube.authorizer = self.googleAuth; // If uncommented, works!

    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSubscriptionsListWithPart:@"snippet"];
    query.mine = YES;

    [self.youTube
     executeQuery:query
     completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                         GTLYouTubeChannelListResponse *channelList,
                         NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription); // fails here
            return;
        }

        for (GTLYouTubeSubscription *channel in channelList) {
            NSLog(@"%@", channel.snippet.title);
        }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a direct fix, but you can do this:

Get the access token from a `GTMOAuth2Authentication` object via:

```
auth.accessToken
```

Then set the access token wherever you want to make requests. 
To refresh the token, use this method:

```
[auth 
 authorizeRequest:nil // just to refresh
 completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     // your code here
 }];
```